# Can we add open telemetry to our flutter app?

Tags: flutter, open-telemetry

I have a flutter app. I need to do instrumentation(analytics). I dont want to use firebase analytics. Is there any chance that I could include MS opentelemetry in my flutter app ??

Comment: There is an open issue where this is tracked. I do not think it is supported officially but there might be ways: https://github.com/open-telemetry/community/issues/552